# Report exceeds maximum upload size of Sonar server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Since the upgrade to Sonarqube 6.0, I have not been able to perform analysis on one of my projects.

This project performs a sonar analysis through the maven plugin, and fails with the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project rating-parent: Error 500 on http://sonar.example.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.example.rating-parent&projectName=Rating%20System&projectBranch=develop
```

Inspecting the sonar.log on the server (which sits behind an Apache 2.4 server through AJP)  revealed this stacktrace:

```
2016.08.12 10:50:14 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://sonar.example.com/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.example.rating:rating-parent&projectName=Rating%20System&projectBranch=develop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readPart(ServletRequest.java:93) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readInputStreamParam(ServletRequest.java:76) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.paramAsInputStream(ValidatingRequest.java:74) ~[sonar-plugin-api-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:84) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:109) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:74) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:125) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:94) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:56) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ProfilingFilter.doFilter(ProfilingFilter.java:84) [sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:191) [logback-access-1.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (3736099) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readParam(ServletRequest.java:71) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.readParamOrDefaultValue(ValidatingRequest.java:134) ~[sonar-plugin-api-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:86) ~[sonar-plugin-api-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:68) ~[sonar-plugin-api-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.Request.mandatoryParam(Request.java:63) ~[sonar-plugin-api-6.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:81) ~[sonar-server-6.0.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (3736099) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:811) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

What I gather from it, is that the error is caused by the fact that the size of analysis report being submitted to the Sonarqube server (about 3,7 MB),  is larger than the embedded Tomcat server's upload limit of about 2 MB.

The cumulative size of the files in target/sonar/batch-report is indeed about 3,7 MB, so I guess the stacktrace is right.

I also tried one of our smaller projects (reports totalling about 1,3M) and it works without a problem.

It does not matter whether I run this from our Jenkins server or locally invoking Maven (3.3.9) from the command line.

Assuming there is no way to decrease the report size (is 3,7 MB exceptional?), I could probably fix this by increasing Tomcat's max upload size. I know how to do this in a regular Tomcat installation, but I have no idea how to do this for Sonarqube's embedded Tomcat server.

Comment: You may be interested in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/sonarqube/OkMXQc-1ah8)

Comment: Thanks @G. Ann,  that is exactly my situation! I tried searching for similar threads but could not find any. Guess it wasn't picked up by search engines yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue when using AJP connector, it will be fixed in 6.1 : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7977

Comment: Thank you, now I know what's causing it. I'll wait for the fix and proxy through http for the time being then!

Comment: Using proxy through HTTP is in fact the only solution, as it has been finally decided to not support AJP anymore : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7989